# Data in a DataFrame clears when adding an Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add an index for one row of data. The dataframe will be used to store different values about a specific region. When I try to add an index, the data clears, even though I am adding the data into the dataframe at the same time.

I have tried the below code. All the row values show `NaN`, but when I remove the index parameter, the data appears.

`ages = pd.DataFrame(data=ages,index=['Ardrossan'])`

The DataFrame should show the population of different age groups in Ardrossan.

Comment: What is data? Is it a Series, a DataFrame, a numpy array, or...?

Comment: @SergeBallesta it's a DataFrame

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example? The underlying reason if that if `ages` already have an index, all *elements* for the new index that do not exist in previous one are set to `NaN`. But without more details I cannot tell you what you should do to fix it.

Comment: This is before adding the index. I did `ages.reset_index()` to clear the index that existed before:

     COL: `A   B   C`
ROW: `0    1    2   3`

Now, when trying to add `index=['Ardrossan']`, this happens:

                 COL:   `A        B       C`
ROW `Ardrossan  NaN   NaN  NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is a data frame, pandas tries to match the indexes.

For example

```
ages = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3]}, 
                    index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ages,index=['Ardrossan'])
```

yields

```
            col1
Ardrossan   NaN
```

But

```
ages = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3]}, 
                    index=['a', 'Ardrossan', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ages,index=['Ardrossan'])
```

Then it yields

```
            col1
Ardrossan   2
```

Make sure you have `Ardrossan` index in your previous data frame. Or, just set the index afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand what you mean. However, the ages DataFrame was transposed (before the `col` in your example was the `index`). I think when I did it pandas must've thought there was a index when I transposed it (when there wasn't post-Transposition)

Comment: I kept it how it was before I transposed it, added `Ardrossan` as a column, then transposed it. It appeared as I wanted it. A way to trick the system, I suppose. Thanks for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 0):

If data is a type having an index like a DataFrame or Series, `pd.DataFrame(data=..., index=...)` only keep rows that have same index in the previous and new index. All other rows with new index receive `NaN`.

So here, you must use the underlying numpy array for data instead of the full dataframe:

```
ages = pd.DataFrame(data=ages.values,index=['Ardrossan'])
```